# How to find commas amongst any letters in strings and remove commas using regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, csv

I use code:
    import sys 
    import os
    import re

```
fa = open('C:\\file1.txt', 'r')
fb = open('C:\\file2.txt', 'w')
for line in fa:
    fb.write(line.replace(([a-z][\,][a-z]),([a-z][a-z]))
fa.close()            
fb.close()
```

file1.txt contains strings `Save,Buy,Go` and `Build,do,it`. I need regex expressions to change the strings to SaveBuyG Builddoit.

I tried `regex` above but it does not work. I need to find in strings parts with commas between letters.

The commas shall be deleted in strings  while reading file1 (note there are no whitespaces between words) in order to convert in standard way to csv.

If the code is not compatible with regex can you paste necessary code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fileinput = open('INFILE.txt', 'r')
fileoutput = fileinput.read()
#fileinput.close()
replace = re.sub(r'([A-Za-z]),([A-Za-z])', r'\1', fileoutput)
print replace
replaceout = open('OUTFILE.txt', 'w')
replaceout.write(replace)

#CHANGE TO r'\1' OR r'\1\2' DEPENDING HOW MANY COMMAS YOU SEE AMONG LETTERS
#WORKING CODE TO READ FILE FINDING AND DELETING COMMAS AMONG LETTERS AND 
#WRITING TO NEW FILE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.sub` from the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) with [lookahead assertions](http://code.runnable.com/Uqc1Tqv_MVNfAAGN/lookahead-and-lookbehind-in-regular-expressions-in-python-for-regex):

```
>>> re.sub('([a-zA-Z]),(?=[a-zA-Z])', r'\1', 'SaveBuyGo Builddoit to Builddoit 1,2 a,b,c,d Save,Buy,Go') 
'SaveBuyGo Builddoit to Builddoit 1,2 abcd SaveBuyGo'
```

Note that it removes the comma between `Build` and `do`, but not between `1` and `2`.

Comment: This would not do quite what the user asks. `re.sub('([a-z]),(?=[a-z])', r'\1', 'Save,Buy,Go') ==
'Save,Buy,Go'`.  You would want to use a different match than `[a-z]`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use regex with string.replace function. In your case you could use re package if you insist on regex:

```
import re
re.sub(r'([A-Za-z]),([A-Za-z])', r'\1\2','Save,Buy,Go , Build,do,it')
```

the output will be:

```
'SaveBuyGo , Builddoit'
```